# webGL ambient lighting without textures on object

Tags: javascript, webgl, shader, lighting

I have been following [these tutorials](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217) which were good, but I can't seem to figure out how to light an object which doesn't have a texture on in. I mean that the shader given in the tutorials doesn't allow the object being drawn to not having a texture. I'm having trouble explaining this but I don't think dumping huge amounts of code here would help if someone who knows how the webGL lighting works.

Could you give an example on using it on a simple pyramid object?

I do have normals for all the triangles in the polygon so that is not the problem.

Comment: Probably the only thing you need to know is that `sampler2D` defines a texture in GLSL, and `texture2D` (and similar functions) get a particular pixel from such a texture. So find the variable with that type, and replace the function calls with a solid colour.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way it just to use a 1x1 pixel white texture when you don't want to use a texture.

```
tex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
              new Uint8Array([255, 255, 255, 255]));
```

Otherwise you need a different shader, one that doesn't take a texture. That means your code gets more complicated managing different paths through the code. If you want to go that route though, look in the shader for `texture2D` and replace it with a color.  For example if the code is

```
gl_FragCoord = texture2D(u_samplers, v_texcoord);
```

Change it to

```
gl_FragCoord = vec4(1,0,0,1);  // just use red
```

or if you want to be able to set it then

```
uniform vec4 u_color;

gl_FragCoord = u_color;  // get color from uniform
```

You can now set that color with

```
// at init time
colorLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_color");

// at draw time
gl.uniform4fv(colorLocation, [1, 0, 0, 1]);  // set color to red
```